# Copy constructor from parent object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, constructor

I have an external Python package `foobar` with a class `foo` with a property `qux` and a method `bar`. I want to extend it.

```
import foobar

class myfoo(foobar.foo):
    def __init__(self, value, *args, **kwargs)
        self.myqux = value #my new property in the extended class
        super(myfoo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def mybaz(self):
        print('My new method in the extended class')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<myfoo Object: qux="{self.qux}"; myqux="{self.myqux}">'
```

Now, there is a method `bar` that returns a `foo`.

```
quuz = foobar.bar()
quuz.baz()
#quuz.mybaz()
print(quuz)
```

Is there a way I can assign the output of `bar` to a `myfoo`? Something like:

```
quuz = myfoo.copy(foobar.qux())
quuz.baz()
quuz.mybaz()
print(quuz)
```

I don't have control on the implementation of `foobar`, and as an external package it might get updated so using a parameter by parameter copy of `foo` is not a desirable idea.

Comment: Your going to have to implement this yourself, if the writers of that package implemented `bar` by hardcoding `foo()` then there's no great way to avoid breakage

Comment: So you want to assign an instance of the superclass to an instance of the subclass? How is that supposed to work? And where would you get the correct value for the "new" (in the subclass) field from?

Comment: Using python naming conventions (which you should stick to, so CapCase for class names) one way you might implement `MyFoo.bar` could simply be `foo= super().bar(); myfoo = MyFoo(); myfoo.__dict__.update(foo.__dict); return myfoo`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I get AttributeError: '`Foo`' object has no attribute '`__dict__`'

Comment: Yikes, yeah then you are going to have to manually do it. Well, check if it had a `__slots__` first.

Comment: neither a `__slots__` attribute.

Comment: Yep, then you don't really have a choice. Is this class written as a C extension?